# Call to void method with parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods

I am calling the void method

```
printDivisors(inputNum)
```

and getting this error:

```
'void' type not allowed here
```

I concatenate the call to the method in a string and the compiler keeps complaining...

Here is the call to a method in a code:

```
if (determinePrime(inputNum)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prime");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Prime" + printDivisors(inputNum));
}
```

Below you can see the full program:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class method_01 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String input;
        int inputNum;

        // Determine Prime

        do {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number please");
            inputNum = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } while (inputNum < 1 );

        if (determinePrime(inputNum)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prime");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Prime" + printDivisors(inputNum));
        }
    }

    // Determine Prime Method

    public static boolean determinePrime(int num) {

        for (int i = 2; i < num ; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Print all the divisors of a number

    public static void printDivisors(int number) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++ ) {

            if (number % i == 0)

                System.out.print("\t" + i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration is void here:

```
public static void printDivisors(int number)
```

If you are using it inside the function, you should return a string instead.
i.e. write to a string instead of

```
System.out.print("\t" + i);
```

and use + to append the string at the end of your code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Prime" + printDivisors(inputNum));}
```

Comment: public static String printDivisors(int number)

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan for your quick response. I am new to java that is why ran into this issue... Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Prime" + printDivisors(inputNum));
```

I suppose you are trying to print the divisor, but it returns null so ideally, when the compiler compiles, it searches for a value, as you have " + " sign after "Not Prime", but does not get anything. thus it is throwing an exception.

either change the return type of printDivisors method or remove that part from the parameter.

Comment: A method that *doesn't return anything* is different than a method that returns `null`.

Comment: Hi Saurabh! Thank you for your quick response. I am new to Java that is why might not understand why that happened. Just to clarify for myself, printDivisors method is a void method, I thought it doesn't return anything and just prints..

Comment: you are right it does not return anything, but when you are using it in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Prime" + printDivisors(inputNum)); the copiler is expecting some return value from the method